# eventbinding issue in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to bind event in directive for textbox.But for some reason its not triggering 
here is my directive

```
angular.module('ui.event',[]).directive('uiEvent', ['$parse',


 function ($parse) {
    return function ($scope, elm, attrs) {
      var events = $scope.$eval(attrs.uiEvent);
      angular.forEach(events, function (uiEvent, eventName) {console.log("hi");
        var fn = $parse(uiEvent);
        elm.bind(eventName, function (evt) {
            console.log("hi1");
          var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
          //Take out first paramater (event object);
          params = params.splice(1);
          fn($scope, {$event: evt, $params: params});
          if (!$scope.$$phase) {
              console.log("hi3");
            $scope.$apply();
          }
        });
      });
    };
  }]);
```

here is the controller

```
  $scope.changeClass = function (options) {
        var widget = options.methods.widget();
        // remove default class, use bootstrap style
        widget.removeClass('ui-menu ui-corner-all ui-widget-content').addClass('dropdown-menu');
    };
       $scope.myOption = {
        options: {
            html: true,
            minLength: 1,
            onlySelectValid: true,
            outHeight: 50,
            source: function (request, response) {
                var data = [
                        "Asp",
                        "BASIC",
                        "C",
                        "C++",
                        "Clojure",
                        "COBOL",
                        "ColdFusion",
                        "Erlang",
                        "Fortran",
                        "Groovy",
                        "Haskell",
                        "Java",
                        "JavaScript",
                        "Lisp",
                        "Perl",
                        "PHP",
                        "Python",
                        "Ruby",
                        "Scala",
                        "Scheme"
                ];
                data = $scope.myOption.methods.filter(data, request.term);

                if (!data.length) {
                    data.push({
                        label: 'not found',
                        value: null
                    });
                }
                // add "Add Language" button to autocomplete menu bottom
                data.push({
                    label: $compile('<a class="ui-menu-add" ng-click="add()">Add Language</a>')($scope),
                    value: null
                });
                response(data);
            }
        },
        events: {
            change: function (event, ui) {
                console.log('change', event, ui);
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                console.log('select', event, ui);
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.add = function () {
        alert('You can do some thing!');
    };
```

here is html

```
<input style="width: 200px" ng-model="modelObj" ui-event="{autocompletecreate:'changeClass(myOption)'}" ui-autocomplete="myOption">
```

I am injective the directive module in my app module but event is not binding 
any suggestion what could be wrong

Comment: u need to give the div uiEvent   <input style="width: 200px" ng-model="modelObj" ui-event="{autocompletecreate:'changeClass(myOption)'}" ui-autocomplete="myOption" uiEvent >

Comment: can you clear your code, Its confusing

Comment: just add "uiEvent >" instead of ">" in ur div ur missing the uiEvent

Comment: Can we see all of your directives code?